# MenuBar is not showing

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

The mx MenuBar is not showing one of the menu items. It was working fine until a few minutes ago. I didn't change any of the code. I noticed when I click on it it shows a shadow.

```
    <mx:MenuBar id="mainMenuBar" 
                dataProvider="{rootMenu}"
                labelField="label"
                height="100%"
                useHandCursor="true"
                buttonMode="true"
                showRoot="false"
                menuShow="menuItemEventHandler(event)" 
                menuHide="menuItemEventHandler(event)"
                itemClick="menuItemEventHandler(event)" 
                itemRollOut="menuItemEventHandler(event)"
                itemRollOver="menuItemEventHandler(event)" 
                change="menuItemEventHandler(event)"
                >
    </mx:MenuBar>

        /**
         * 
         * */
        private function menuItemEventHandler(event:MenuEvent):void {

            if (event.item is MenuItem) {
                EventDispatcher(event.item).dispatchEvent(event);
            } 
            else if (event.menu && event.menu.dataProvider && 
                event.menu.dataProvider[0] is MenuItem && 
                event.menu.dataProvider[0].parent is MenuItem)
            {
                EventDispatcher(event.menu.dataProvider[0].parent).dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        }



    <model:MenuItem id="rootMenu">
        <model:MenuItem label="Edit" >
            <model:MenuItem id="undo" label="Undo" />
            <model:MenuItem id="redo" label="Redo" />
            <model:MenuItem type="separator"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="cut" label="Cut" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="copy" label="Copy" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="paste" label="Paste" name="paste" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="undo1" label="Undo" />
            <model:MenuItem id="redo1" label="Redo" />
            <model:MenuItem type="separator"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="cut1" label="Cut" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="copy1" label="Copy" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="paste1" label="Paste" name="paste" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="undo2" label="Undo" />
            <model:MenuItem id="redo2" label="Redo" />
            <model:MenuItem type="separator"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="cut2" label="Cut" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="copy2" label="Copy" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="paste2" label="Paste" name="paste" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="undo3" label="Undo" />
            <model:MenuItem id="redo3" label="Redo" />
            <model:MenuItem type="separator"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="cut3" label="Cut" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="copy3" label="Copy" enabled="false"/>
            <model:MenuItem id="paste3" label="Paste" name="paste" enabled="false"/>
        </model:MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the height of the menu was taller than the height of the application. So it ***was*** displaying but it was off the screen. I'm guessing the logic is that if any part of the menu pop up is off the screen the menubar must be positioned along the bottom of the application so the pop up should display above the menu bar instead of below it.

The workaround was to make the screen taller (I had Firebug visible so it was not the typical height). I could check for the height of the pop up and compare it to the height of the application and manually set the pop up vertical position to the right location. I haven't tried to solve it beyond this point since the user will probably not ever use the application at this short of a height.